# Number of solutions to quadratic congruence

Tags: number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

> For every positive integer $b$, show that there exists a positive
>   integer $n$ such that the polynomial ${x^2} - 1 \in
> (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})[x]$ has at least $b$ roots.

**My efforts**

Let $n = {p_1} \ldots {p_k}$, where ${p_i}$ is $i$-th prime number. Let us choose such $x$ for which $x-1$ is divisible by ${p_1} \ldots {p_i}$ and $x + 1$ is divisible by ${p_{i+1}} \ldots {p_k}$. The existence of such $x$ is guaranteed by CRT. Changing $i$ we get different solutions for $x$ modulo $n$. Indeed, if ${p_1} \ldots {p_j} \mid x-1$ and ${p_{j + 1}} \ldots {p_k} \mid x+1$ such that $i < j$, then both $x+1$ and $x-1$ are divisible by ${p_j} > 2$, which is impossible.

Comment: Not a divisor of, is divisible by. More strongly, we could choose $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p_i}$, for the $2^n$ possible choices of sign, giving us $2^n\gt n$ solutions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanx for the correction. Could you please clarify the last sentence? How to show it rigorously?

Comment: It is CRT, like you used.

Comment: @AndréNicolas OK :)